# What does "CP" stand for? (job name)

Tags: abbreviations, business-language

I saw a person had described his position as "CP at example.com" on Linkedin.

Not someone who I know personally, but I had been in contact when he asked me to publish my Android application on this website (a kind of apps market in China).

Just curious, what does CP means? I search on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP) and abbreviations website to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the context, I'd say it's either *computer programmer* or *content producer*.

There are a few other professions that use the abbreviation, but likely aren't applicable:

- certified paralegal
- certified practioner

Both use *CP* as a suffix (like *Esq.*, *CPA*, and *MD* are used for lawyers, accountants, and doctors, respectively).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the latter in that context and web site.

Comment: @Joe I've seen many non-American programmers refer to themselves as *CP*, so I'm not particularly convinced it's  one or the other. A website for the Android market is likely a startup where employees wear multiple hats, and I wouldn't be surprised if a developer of the site was reaching out to other programmers.

Comment: interesting, Mark, thanks.  Aside, another point -- you know on sites like that, people are often looking for, you know, "scam" content generation -- in relation to "SEO", do you know what I mean?  As in "create 45x 100 word essays about mattress construction for $95...!!"  Do you know what I mean?  I believe, that particular type of "content production" is usually referred to as "CP" (I used to use those sites a lot and you have to cut through the "scam CP / SEO" entries!)  Re the particular company at hand, I'm sure it's just what you describe, CP = computer programmers.

Answer (score 2):

That might stand for "Corporate President".

Answer (score 0):

In the telecommunications industry, *CP* stands for "Communication Provider".

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?  Also, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Among other abbreviations having more than one use, *[CP](http://www.acronymfinder.com/CP.html)* also stands for *[Certified Paralegal](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Certified-Paralegal-(CP).html)*.

It means not only have you taken an American Bar Association approved degree program at an accredited school but you have also taken and passed the Accredited Legal Professional Certification Examination (ALP) and passed it. You don't hear about too many people having CP as Post Nominal abbreviations because the pass rate for the ALP is 45-50%.

CP is not to be confused with a Certificated Paralegal which means they only got a Certificate and not a degree. The CP exam is a national examination but there are a few states that have there own state bar rules to become a CP.

*acronymfinder.com*

Comment: If you're quoting another site, can you format your answer so we can exactly what is quoted and what is your commentary?

Answer (score -3):

Competent person in a field of engineering. Especially in building of new projects.